# iOS Build fails due to certifications, but they were created in the wizard

Tags: codenameone

I have been using codenameone to develop an app which I have tested on android, and wish to do so on iOS. I have a paid Apple Developer account, and am able to go through the signing wizard correctly and the "iOS Signing" page is filled out with all of the information.

However, when I come to build an iOS development build, during the ant process the console logs

```
A certificate from Apple with the appropriate password is required for building an iOS native app!
```

This is odd, as the information that was filled in was created from the wizard with no errors. On th Apple Developer account page I can see all of the certificates and devices etc...

Comment: Check that you used the wizard from Codename One Settings and not the one from the preferences UI. Also make sure you saved after the wizard finished. Check the paths/files are filled out in the iOS signing section

Comment: @ShaiAlmog How do you access this in IntelliJ? I am currently clicking the icon in the top right > Code Name One Preferences > iOS Certification Wizard

Comment: In intellij the only option is the Codename One Settings app so that shouldn't be a problem. After you run the wizard make sure you press the save button on the top right. Then verify everything was setup correctly in the iOS signing section within the settings.

Comment: @ShaiAlmong I have done that, and the information seems correct, but for the password will it by default be my apple ID password or a password generated for that certificate? Should I retype it in to be sure?

Comment: The certificate password will be "password"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, (even when I clicked "browse") when I selected the certificate files it would change the path to my JDK installation

```
/Library......bin/<selected file>
```

This is odd, but I ended up fixing it by manually creating the certificates (being unaware of the certificate password.) Trying now, it [the certificate creator] works fine (as long as I change the path once it has finished). It wouldn't allow any full path (IE /Users/....), and would only allow relative paths to the project folder. So when I set the location to the "iosCerts" folder, it worked fine.

```
iosCerts/<selected file>
```

This possibly may be an IntelliJ / Mac bug?